# Display users with x amount data in another table

Tags: mysql

I am trying to display users from "users" table with 20 or more entries in another table called "property_item" table. Property item table has user_id column. I tried the following code but i am stuck where i need to specify amount of entry in property_item table. The below code is unfinished.

```
SELECT * 
FROM users 
INNER JOIN property_item 
ON 
    users.active = 1 && 
    users.username != 'admin' && 
    users.type = 3 && 
    property_item.user_id = users.user_id 

ORDER BY username ASC
```

Any opinion how i should continue with the query?

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might help you:

```
SELECT * FROM users
JOIN property_item
ON property_item.user_id = users.user_id
WHERE
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM property_item
 WHERE user_id = users.user_id) >= 20
GROUP by users.user_id 
ORDER BY username ASC
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. This query seems to work but it is displaying the same user with the amount of data it has instead of displaying once.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go...

```
SELECT * 
FROM users
Where users.active = 1 AND
users.username != 'admin' AND 
users.type = 3 AND 
exists (Select user_id , count(1) 
From  property_item 
property_item.user_id = users.user_id 
group by user_id 
having count(1) > 20
)
ORDER BY user.username ASC
```